# Running matlab on Windows through Mac

Tags: macos, mac, memory, virtual-machine, ramdisk

I need to do some work on matlab which must be through windows. Unfortunately I have a 2014 mid retina (8gb ram, core i5). Would one think I would be able to run it through parallel? I need to do some pretty ram exhausting work and I'm afraid it won't be enough ? What does everyone think ? Any advice ?

Thanks

Comment: Performance should better if you use Bootcamp.  You can also just use the OS X version of Matlab.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use a toolbox feature that is only compatible with Windows... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance will be better if you use bootcamp. You could also use virtual box but bootcamp would be better.
Step by step tutorial on how to setup bootcamp: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201468

Comment: By the way, just wondering... is it because of the additional ram hogged by the virtual machinery that will cause this to be slower ?

Comment: So because your running windows in side of OS X there still needs to be available resources to run OS X there for you are limited on the amount of resources you can use that is why bootcamp is better because it is only running windows.